# How to Increase the Height of Silverlight Datagrid Header

Tags: silverlight

I am new to silver Light. How to Increase the Height of Silverlight Datagrid Header

I am using  template column

Code as follows :

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Base Receipt"> 
      <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
          <DataTemplate> 
              <Grid> 
                  <sdk:Label Margin="5,0,5,0" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/> 
              </Grid> 
          </DataTemplate> 
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HeaderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.headerstyle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) :

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Base Receipt">
  <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
      <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
      </Style>
  </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
  <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
      <DataTemplate> 
          <Grid> 
              <sdk:Label Margin="5,0,5,0" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/> 
          </Grid> 
      </DataTemplate> 
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```